# Fire an event on enter button press in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-button, lightning-events, keyboard

I am trying to implement a button that will fire a search event when it is clicked and also when enter button is pressed. How to listen to the enter button press? This is the code for my button.

```
    <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small"
    variant="brand"
    name="search"
    label="Search"
    onclick={handleSearch}>
    </lightning-button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this by using `onkeypress` and checking that the pressed key is 13.

```
<lightning-input
        type="search"
          onchange={handleSearchKeyChange}
        label="Search..."
        value={searchKey}
        onkeypress={handleEnter}> 
 </lightning-input>

  <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small"
variant="brand"
name="search"
label="Search”
onclick={handleSearch}>
</lightning-button>



 handleEnter(event){
    if(event.keyCode === 13){
      this.handleSearch();
    }
  }
```

Comment: sorry it is not working

Comment: You need to put the onkeypress in your input tag. I updated my answer to show this.

Answer (score 1):

[The Mozilla documentation says keypress is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event). Might be better to use `keydown` instead.